Finding an explicit formula for a norm induced by an inner product
$\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is an inner product defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\| \cdot \|$ is the norm induced by it. The norm satisfies the following conditions:
$$
\sup_{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2} \frac{\| \boldsymbol{x} \|_2}{\| \boldsymbol{x} \|} = 3 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \inf_{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2} \frac{\| \boldsymbol{x} \|_2}{\| \boldsymbol{x} \|} = 1
$$
Additionally, we know that $\| (1, 2) \| = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3}$ and $\| (-2, 1) \| = \sqrt{5}$. I'm supposed to find an explicit formula for $\| \cdot \|$.
It's easy to notice that the points correspond to the supremum and infimum of the fraction of the norms. Using homogeneity, we can reduce the problem to a set smaller than the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, e.g. $\mathcal{S} = \{ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2 \, : \, \| \boldsymbol{x} \|_2 = 1 \}$. From there, we obtain
$$
\inf_{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathcal{S}} \| \boldsymbol{x} \| = \frac{1}{3} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sup_{\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathcal{S}} \| \boldsymbol{x} \| = 1
$$
For any quadratic form $q$ induced by an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a basis $\mathcal{B} = (\boldsymbol{v}_1, \ldots, \boldsymbol{v}_n)$ and constants $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n > 0$ such that
$$
q\left( \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k \boldsymbol{v}_k,  \right) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \alpha_k a_k^2
$$
We can then study an equation
$$
q(\boldsymbol{x}) = 1,
$$
which, in the case of $n = 2$, defines an ellipse.
The points from the problem should then, intuitively, correspond to the axes of the ellipse and so for some basis $\mathcal{B} = (\boldsymbol{v}_1, \boldsymbol{v}_2)$, we should be able to write
$$
\| x(1, 2) + y(-2, 1) \|^2 = ax^2 + by^2
$$
for some constants $a, b > 0$. Finding those constants is easy.
However, what I described is a high-level plan to tackle the problem. Unfortunately, it relies on my intuitions (like the vectors corresponding to the axes of the ellipse) that I don't know how to formalise.
I'd appreciate it if someone could write a formal solution to this problem so I can learn from it.

Can you clarify what you mean by the norm, versus the norm-sub-two? ...

@paulgarrett norm-sub-two is the norm induced by the standard inner product. The other norm—the one without the subscript—is the norm induced by the unknown inner product

An inner product on $\mathbb R^2$ is in general characterised by a symmetric positive-definite matrix $A$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle=x^TAy$. The conditions with $\sup$ and $\inf$ that you provided indicate that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $\frac19$. So there is a $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ such that
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & \frac19
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)\\
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos^2(\theta)+\frac19\sin^2(\theta) & \frac89\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\\
\frac89\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) & \frac19\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
=\frac1{9(1+t^2)}\begin{pmatrix}
9+t^2 & 8t\\
8t & 1+9t^2
\end{pmatrix}$$
where in the last step we have applied the substitution $t=\tan(\theta)$.
Now we have $\lVert (-2,1) \rVert^2 = 5$ which means that $4(9+t^2)-32t+(1+9t^2)=45(1+t^2)$ which rearranges to $(1+2t)^2=0$, i.e. $t=-\frac12$. Therefore
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{37}{45} & -\frac{16}{45}\\
-\frac{16}{45} & \frac{13}{45}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
